# How to query a json file on a server

Tags: javascript, json, server

How to "query" a json file on server with javascript?
Filtering on server side, with ajax request.

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Something like "select * from emplyees like 'J%'. Shold avoid using db. Just use simple json file and be able to get only filteted data from server. 
Need a simple, fast way to get obly needed data, using json file instead of db. Without need to install database

Thanks in advance, best regards
Massimo

Comment: Might need to fix your title from CSV to JSON. Also check the filter() function.

Comment: You'd make an Ajax request to get the JSON down to the browser, you'd then use `JSON.parse()` to convert that to an object, and you'd then (perhaps) use `.filter()` on the `employees` array. (Or do you want the filtering to occur on the server side?)

Comment: Are you wanting to use ajax?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it will work  http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

```
{
"key" : "value",
"array" : [
    { "key" : 1 },
    { "key" : 2, "dictionary": {
            "a": "Apple",
            "b": "Butterfly",
            "c": "Cat",
            "d": "Dog"
        } },
    { "key" : 3 }
]
```

}

```
$.array[?(@.key=2)].dictionary.b
```

RESULT

```
  [
        "Butterfly"
  ]
```

Comment: The need is to avoid download all json data from server, for performance reasons. Need to filter on server side. Best without installing database on server side. Need to work only with plain files.

Comment: yes i now only small data